# Perl hex string to binary string

Tags: perl

I'm trying to convert a string of hex digits to a binary string.  If my input string is 41424344, then I would want the string to store "ABCD".  How can this be done?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it without using regex with help of [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html):

```
print pack 'H*', '41424344';
```

Output:

```
ABCD
```

Answer (score 1):

The canonical method is

```
$input_string =~ s/(..)/chr(hex($1))/ge;
```

This reads two characters at a time from the input, calling `hex` (converting a hexidecimal number to a decimal number) and then `chr` (converting a decimal number to a character) on each input.

Comment: @daxim - Citing anything as canon in Perl risks starting a holy war and I respect your difference of opinion. The `CGI` module currently uses the `.../chr hex $1/ge` idiom, but upon further research I find that its technique to unescape HTML has gone through many other incarnations.

Comment: Lincoln Stein, the creator of CGI.pm, was anything but canonical. He invented ways of doing things that nobody else would use. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
s/([a-f0-9][a-f0-9])/chr(hex($1))/egi;
```